# Ubuntu 13.10/Gnome shell keeps asking me for my e-mail accounts passwords but says they are wrong. How can I fix this?

Tags: gnome, password, 13.10, email, gmail

Ubuntu 13.10/Gnome shell keeps asking me for my e-mail accounts passwords but says they are wrong.

After login, in gnome shell, it asks for my two email accounts passwords. When I insert them it tells me they're wrong. I cancel and a bit after it asks me again. Over and over.

I think this has something to do with the evolution gnome-shell extension but I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Go to the shell/terminal

```
$ cd .config
$ cd goa-1.0
$ mv accounts.conf ../../Desktop
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach (to jelofson) - see [Why does ubuntu 13.10 keep asking for my gmail password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366399/why-does-ubuntu-13-10-keep-asking-for-my-gmail-password) Still don't know what the problem is though, his answer suggests it's a bug in goa-1.0