# Why won't my Ubuntu GNOME accept my google password?

Tags: online-accounts, ubuntu-gnome

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 14.04. I integrated my Google account with it. But every time I login GNOME asks for my google account password. But when I give it, it simply wont accept it! I am 100% sure I am typing the right password for my google account(It doesn't have 2 step verification at present. I was using it before but not now.) Since it didn't work I tried my login password but that too didn't work. Then I removed integration for that account from "Online Accounts" then removed all my cache and tried integrating again. It integrates, but again, if I type in my password when asked for, the same issue persists. Here is a screen shot:

(asking for password:)

[image]

---

(after right password is given:)

[image]

I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/366399/225679) answer partly(I deleted `goa-1.0` but not `evolution` since it would delete my evolution configuration which I want!) But deleting `goa-1.0` didn't let me integrate my google account at all and so it doesn't work!(I recreated `goa-1.0` and now I can reintegrate my account but the password issue persists).

So now my question is: **How do I integrate my google account with my Ubuntu GNOME without any such issues as explained above?**

PS:- Should I be doing something with `seahorse` here? I dunno how it works and all and so if I have to use it, tell me what to do elaborately.

Comment: No. As I say above "It doesn't have 2 step verification at present. I was using it before but not now."

Comment: okay..will try..

Comment: Doesn't seem to work! So I integrated, it asked for the password and I gave my app specific password..but..it wont accept!!! That's weird !

Comment: Is this a bug??!!

Comment: I mean I have the same problem, and haven't managed to solve it.

Comment: So I tried something...I disintegrated my google account from GNOME. Then went to 'evolution' and connected 'evolution' to my google account and it works fine! Evolution(like GNOME) asked for my password, I gave it my password and it doesn't ask it any more! Works like a dream! So this is clearly a problem with the account integration in GNOME.

Comment: Exactly the same problem...and the same solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with GNOME accounts integration feature. To solve this issue, for the time being, one might use evolution instead of integrating one's account with GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug: [#1353951](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/1353951).
It will be fixed with the last version of [evolution-data-server](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-data-server/3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3) (still in 'proposed').

Answer (score 1):

From [Google's help](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121101311/https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en):

> Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps or devices that do
>   not use modern security standards. Since these apps and devices are
>   easier to break into, blocking them helps keep your account safe.
>
> Some examples of apps that do not support the latest security
>   standards include:
>
> - The Mail app on your iPhone or iPad with iOS 6 or below
> - The Mail app on your Windows phone preceding the 8.1 release
> - Some Desktop mail clients like Microsoft Outlook and Mozilla Thunderbird

You have two options:

> - Option 1: Upgrade to a more secure app that uses the most up to date security measures. All Google products, like Gmail, use the latest
>     security measures.
> - Option 2: Change your settings to allow less secure apps to access your account. We don't recommend this option because it might make it
>     easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow
>     access anyway, follow these steps:
>
>   - Go to the "Less secure apps" section in My Account.
>   - Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has
>       locked less secure app account access.)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I tried to integrate my google calendar into Gnome calendar, but setting up google online accounts caused the problem described here.
- I had to remove google online account from Gnome
- Set up Evolution to use my google account including google calendar
Problem solved.
G

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu 14.04. I thought that I had corrected it by deleting the failing account and reinstalling the account information. However, the problem came back.

So I looked harder and found that somehow an account setting had changed (damn gremlins!).

Here's a check.

If your system starts prompting for a password and won't accept the one you enter, edit the settings for the account that is failing (edit->preferences->edit).

Under Receiving Email, check the Authentication pull-down. If it says Password, that's the problem because Password is not a valid selection.

Click Check for Supported Types and select the one that does not have a line through it.

Restart Evolution and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing less secure app from below link:

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Found this answer from reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/7qeq6y/how_to_fix_issue_with_google_login/dsosg2s?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3